# Creating recursive function for nested loop in python

Tags: python, recursion

I had posted this question :
[Non overlapping pattern matching with gap constraint in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490525/non-overlapping-pattern-matching-with-gap-constraint-in-python) ; two months back. I got only one response. But the solution is quite long, and for each word in a pattern, one nested loop is formed. Is there any way of forming the following function recursively ?

```
i=0
while i < len(pt_dic[pt_split[0]]):
    match=False
    ii = pt_dic[pt_split[0]][i]
    #print "ii=" + str(ii)

    # Start loop at next index after ii
    j = next(x[0] for x in enumerate(pt_dic[pt_split[1]]) if x[1] > ii)
    while j < len(pt_dic[pt_split[1]]) and not match:
        jj = pt_dic[pt_split[1]][j]
        #print "jj=" + str(jj)
        if jj > ii and jj <= ii + 2:

            # Start loop at next index after ii
            k = next(x[0] for x in enumerate(pt_dic[pt_split[2]]) if x[1] > jj)
            while k < len(pt_dic[pt_split[2]]) and not match:
                kk = pt_dic[pt_split[2]][k]
                #print "kk=" + str(kk)
                if kk > jj and kk <= jj + 2:

                    # Start loop at next index after kk
                    l = next(x[0] for x in enumerate(pt_dic[pt_split[3]]) if x[1] > kk)
                    while l < len(pt_dic[pt_split[2]]) and not match:
                        ll = pt_dic[pt_split[3]][l]
                        #print "ll=" + str(ll)
                        if ll > kk and ll <= kk + 2:
                            print "Match: (" + str(ii) + "," + str(jj) + "," + str(kk) + "," + str(ll) + ")"
                            # Now that we've found a match, skip indices within that match.
                            i = next(x[0] for x in enumerate(pt_dic[pt_split[0]]) if x[1] > ll)
                            i -= 1
                            match=True
                        l += 1
            k += 1
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

Edit : **For those who don't get the context :**

I want to find total no. of non-overlapping matches of a pattern appearing in a sequence, with the gap constraint 2.

Eg. `A B C` is a pattern found using some algorithm. I have to find the total # of this pattern appearing in a sequence such as `A  A  B  B  C  D E  A  B  C …` , where the max gap constraint is 2.

Max. gap isn't seen across sequence, but is seen between two words belonging to a pattern that are substring in sequence. E.g. `Pat: A B C` and `seq: A B D E C B A B A B C D E`.

In this case, `A B D E C ...` is a match as max two gaps allowed between A,B and B, C. Next we find `A B A B C` as another match. Interestingly. there are two matches, (2 chars b/w A, B and 2 chars b/w B,C) . However, we will count it only as one, as it's an overlapping match. `A B X X X C` isn't valid.

Comment: Restating your goal here would be nice, even if it's just a copy-paste of the other post.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the original question only briefly. I'm not really sure if I've got the gap counting part right. I think you have L sorted sequences of unique indices and the code searches for all lists with L elements, where Nth element is from Nth sequence and where two adjacent items satisfy a condition `prev < next < prev + GAP + 1`

Anyway this question is about nested loops.

The basic idea of the code below is to pass a list of sequences to the recursive function. This function takes the first sequence from it and iterates over it. The remaining sequences are passed to the other instances of the same function where each instance does the same, i.e. iterates over the first sequence and passes the rest until no sequences to iterate over are left.

During that process a partial solution is being built step by step. The recursion continues only if this partial solution satisfies the condition. When all sequences are exhausted, the partial solution becomes a final solution.

```
list_of_seqs= [
    [0, 1, 7, 11, 22, 29],
    [2, 3, 8, 14, 25, 33],
    [4, 9, 15, 16, 27, 34],
]


def found_match(m):
    print(m)

GAP = 2 
def recloop(part, ls):
    if not ls: 
        found_match(part)
        return
    seq, *ls = ls   # this is Python3 syntax
    last = part[-1] if part else None
    # this is not optimized:
    for i in seq:
        if last is None or last < i <= last + GAP + 1:
            recloop(part + [i], ls) 

recloop([], list_of_seqs)
```

For Python2 replace the marked line with `seq, ls = ls[0], ls[1:]`

Comment: I have added the question context, so you can get what is the main purpose.

Comment: @user1991470 There was a two step solution shown in the original question, the indices (positions of pattern elements) were computed in the first step, and they were processed in the second step using nested loops. The number of loops needed was determined by the length of the pattern. The code could process only one fixed pattern length. My answer shows how to implement nested loops with variable depth. Please adjust the code if it does not implement your rules for special pattern matching correctly. I did not focus on the broad context, but on the question itself.